# load innerHtml of ajax loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div which get's its content loaded through ajax .load("ajaxcontent.php").

Inside this div, we produce many other divs. I want to get the content of one of these divs.

I've tried var insidecontent=$('#topdiv').html(); but it returns null.

is there a trick to getting such values?

index.html

```
<div id="news"></div>
```

ajaxcontent.php

```
<div id="topdiv">Hello World</div>
<div id="middiv">This is the mid div</div>
<div id="botdiv">This is the bottom</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#news").load("ajaxcontent.php");

$(document).delegate("#total", "keyup", function (e) {
        if(e.which!=13){
            var insidecontent=$('#topdiv').html();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML returned by the ajax load? As well as the HTML for the container div?

Comment: Please show some of your markup.

Comment: Could we see some code please?

Comment: where is your code? If you let us guessing, you wont get good answers.

Comment: I can't post exact code because it's broken into many pieces through many php loops, but I posted the barebone.

Comment: i added another piece, the delegate event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you accessing the content after the load function completes its execution ?

```
$("#firstDiv").load("serverpage.aspx",function(){

      // Now access the content
       var insideContent=$("#topDiv").html();

});
```

EDIT : After the op posted his code

wrap the delegate binding inside document.ready like this

```
$(function(){
  $(document).delegate("#total", "keyup", function (e) {
        if(e.which!=13){
            var insidecontent=$('#topdiv').html();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: onkeyup of a textbox inside this div, the javascript fires to get insideContent. Can you look at my original post I added some code to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#DivForContent').load('ajaxcontent.php #topdiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that you call the `$('#topdiv')` after `topdiv` is attached to the DOM.  `load` take a callback as per http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#someDiv').load('ajaxcontent.php', function() {
    var insidecontent=$('#innerDiv').html();
    //Do something with it.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you showed just `.load("ajaxcontent.php")` I assume you are trying to do this

```
jQuery("#foo").load("ajaxcontent.php")
var insidecontent=$('#topdiv').html()
```

You need to use a callback since load is asynchronous.

```
function finishProcessing() {
    var insidecontent=$('#topdiv').html();
    alert( insidecontent );
}

jQuery("#foo").load("ajaxcontent.php", finishProcessing)
```

Check out the api for [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)